# How to use regex to select rows where the column has more than two words in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

for example:

| id | center |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | man |
| 2 | some men here |

I want to select rows with three or more words so ouput should be:

| id | center |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | some men here |

I've tried using this: `regexp_like(center, '\w{3,}')` but it's not giving the expected output.

Comment: `\w{3,}` is 3 or more letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_COUNT` to look for more than 2 sets of words

```sql
WITH
    some_table (id, center)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'man' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'some men here' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM some_table
 WHERE REGEXP_COUNT (center, '\w+') > 2;
```

Comment: Alternatively you may also look for 2 or more separators depending on the complexity of the word's definition

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex pattern `\w+ \w+ \w+`:

```sql
SELECT id, center
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(center, '\w+[:space:]+\w+[:space:]+\w+);
```

Comment: This would not work correctly if words were separated by anything other than one space (two spaces, new line, etc.)

Comment: This would still not work if the words were separated by anything other than "spaces" such as commas, pipes etc. If you wish to use `REGEXP_LIKE`, you would want a regex expression like this `\w+\W+\w+\W+\w+`

Comment: You are getting speculative now.  Is `one#two` one word, two words, or not even a match?  You are discrediting my answer based on edge cases which we don't know are even really there.

Comment: Possibly, but I still think it would be good for OP to know before choosing the solution to implement in their code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the regex you are looking for:

```
regexp_like(center, '((\s|^)\w+(\s|$)?){3,}')
```

or with a short test:

```
select * from (
    select 'abc' center
    from dual
    union all
    select 'abc def'
    from dual
    union all
    select 'abc def ghi'
    from dual
    union all
    select 'abc def ghi jkl'
    from dual
) 
where regexp_like(center, '((\s|^)\w+(\s|$)?){3,}')
```

It says

```
Start of line or whitespace
One or more letters
Whitespace or end of line, non-greedy
Repeat all of the above at least three times
```